# How to modify the lastmod node in sitemap xml with php

Tags: php, xml

Good day all, I have a standard sitemap xml. Is there any way to update the lastmod tag related to a specific URL automatically with Php?   I havent tried any code yet since i m not very able to program in PHP. Many thanks, any solution Will Be aprechated.

Comment: If you are not able to program it, then you can change it in a text editor.... Or you can use `sed` command if it needs to be automated.

Comment: Ok but there are 47000 URL in the sitemap updating every day i definitely Need It thats why i ve asked for. I can implement every code changing variables or perform some changes but i cannot create this kind of code unfortunately. Thanks anyway.